# jQuery: how to count elements with similiar but dynamic ID

Tags: jquery, count, element

I want to count elements with a certain ID with jquery.
My Application has blocks which have multiple lines which have multiple fields.

my fields have id's like that: "field_B1_L1_1" that would be the first field in the first line.
It's easy to count all fields there are in all blocks:

```
$(":input[id^=field]").length
```

But what am i doing if i want to count all fields in line y from block x?

```
$(":input[id^=field_B{x}_L{y}]").length how can i put the variables in here?
```

Comment: There should only be one element with a specific ID! The result should either by 1 or 0.

Comment: You can try with this `$(\`:input[id^=field_B${x}_L${y}]\`)`

Comment: @phuzi while you are correct on the first part, the op never stated that the id's are the same. `id^=field` takes all elements where the id starts with `field`

Comment: @phuzi my IDs are all specific in one block and one line the ids are "field_B1_L1_1", "field_B1_L1_2", "field_B1_L1_3" and i want to count all elements which id *begins* with "field_B1_L1_" to get all elements in this Line